# add package to android linux system

Tags: android, embedded-linux

I developed new package and I compile it with `OPENWRT` toolchain. And then I install it in `OPENWRT` device.

It is possible to add package to `android Linux system`, like openwrt, and then compile it.

There is a link explain this in details if it is possible  ?

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html) describes the process of how to use android standalone compiler to get what you have described.

You might also want to check your NDK docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html